# Not able to use is_displayed property in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to check if a text(hyperlink) is present or not in the page. If displayed I was click on it. And if not sleep for 5 more seconds.

I've tried

```
if driver.find_element_by_id('xpath').is_displayed:
    driver.find_element_by_id('xpath').click() 
else:
    time.sleep(2)
```

However I'm not able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### is_displayed()

[`is_displayed()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_displayed) method determines whether the element is visible to a user. So essentially your line of code should have been:

```
if driver.find_element_by_id('xpath').is_displayed():
```

Comment: I've tried driver.find_element_by_id('id').is_displayed(): too. However it is still not working. I've driver.get() post which I wait for 10secs. And then search the I'd whether it's visible or not.

Comment: I've added a print under if statement. it does print that the element is displayed. however .click under if statement won't work. :|

Comment: @AkshayKhard this answer was to cater to your requirement of  `is_displayed()` not working properly. For the `click()` requirement can you raise a new question please?

Answer (score 2):

Here it looks like in place of xpath method, you are using id method to find element or vice versa.
It should be
driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')

Comment: I've tried both driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')/i'd('id') still not working.